# How do the men and woman coincidentally have their basketball shirts?

Tags: plot-explanation, grown-ups

As seen in *Grown Ups*, the five main characters near the end are re-challenged by their youth basketball team rivalry. They are on the court and every single man happens to be wearing the basketball shirt from their youth basketball days:

Also notice the sudden appearance of the cheerleader dress the women are wearing.

How is it that every single person there has their basketball gear without prior planning?

Comment: I haven't watched it, but this is a comedy, right? Not every single thing has to make sense, perhaps it's just because they thought the movie would be funnier like this?

Answer (score -1):

I don't remember the whole movie, but I wanna say there was a scene with sewing.....but now thinking about it, right before they play, Adam Sandler tells the guy that they just wanna eat with their families, suggesting that there was no plan to play......good question....have to watch it again now. Lol

Comment: You are right about the sewing scene, but they show up wearing sponsor tee-shirts instead, which is considered a bit of a mistake: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375670/goofs?item=gf2167655 

IMdB and Wikipedia are often good sources for articles or posts supporting your answers.

Answer (score -2):

They are, as title suggest **Grown Ups**. They're supposed to have money. Money that can be exchanged for various goods like made to order basketball outfits.

Also it's way to show that antagonist are cool because they have this cool new shirts while the opposite team is still anchored in their old success so they don't move forward.

Comment: @Gnemlock New ones as in completely new with new design and new ones that look exactly as the old ones.

Comment: The "good guys" have new design. The one that moved on in their life. The "bad guys" have still the same design as the did in HS showing they still hold to that one last success.